# Save and Load Simple Transformer Model

Tags: python, transformer, torch

I have trained Text classifier using simpleTranformer.ai I am struggling to save  and load the model in docker container. Please let me know how can I save the trained model and then load it into different environment smoothly.
I am using this library to : https://simpletransformers.ai/ to train a text model using these commands

```
 model = ClassificationModel('xlmroberta', 'xlm-roberta-base',use_cuda=cuda_available, num_labels=78, args={'learning_rate':1e-5, 'num_train_epochs': 1,'train_batch_size':256,'eval_batch_size':1048, 'n_gpu':4, 'reprocess_input_data': True, 
'overwrite_output_dir':True, 'overwrite_output_dir': True})

model.train_model(train_df)
```

I am saving the trained model using pytorch function:

```
torch.save(model, 'classifier')
```

But its showing error of some missing files when I tried to load this model from different virtual machine. So, I am looking for best alternative to save and load the simpleTransformer model.

Comment: Hi @SKSingh, welcome to the site. You should add more details to the question, e.g. what Transformer library are you using (link to it)? what do you mean by "load" in "load the model in docker container/environment" (e.g. offer it through an API, use it in the command line)?

Comment: Updated the question a bit. Let me know if I need to any more infornation

Answer (score 1):

you just need to save each section to a target path

```
model.model.save_pretrained('model1')
model.tokenizer.save_pretrained('model1')
model.config.save_pretrained('model1/')
```

then you can load like this

```
model = ClassificationModel('roberta','model1')
```

Comment: The best annswer! It helped me thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In PyTorch, the learnable parameters (i.e. weights and biases) of an **torch.nn.Module** model are contained in the model’s parameters (accessed with **model.parameters()**). A **state_dict** is simply a Python dictionary object that maps each layer to its parameter tensor. So, you can save a model in different ways,

1. First way is to store a model like you have stored `torch.save(model.state_dict(), PATH)` and to load the same model on a different machine or some different place then first you have to make the instance of that model and then assign that model to the model parameter like this.

   model = TheModelClass(*args, **kwargs)

after making the instance of the class then load the model like this.

```
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
```

It's a recommended way of saving and loading a model. If you are saving the model then before loading the model on a different machine first make the instance of that model then you can run the model.

2. The other way is to save `model.state_dict()` using **pickle**  `pickle.dump(model.state_dict(), open(filename, 'wb'))` and then load the model by `pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))` but, this isn't a standard way to save and load a model the most recommended way is the first one.

Besides this, if your error couldn't be resolved then you can ask in the comment section.

Answer (score -1):

Your model is stored in **outputs** directory with the name **pytorch_model.bin**.
Go and check that out.